# Construction of Hom from $D_4$ to $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The dihedral $D_4$ group contains the subgroup

$$H=\langle r^2,t\rangle=\{e, r^2,t,tr^2   \}$$

which is normal. A proof is offered [right here](https://youtu.be/ImlGpfd9vRc?t=7m2s), based on the fact that $H$ is the kernel of a homomorphism, $\ker(\phi)=H:$

$$\begin{align}
\phi &:  D_4\to\mathbb Z_2\\
& r \mapsto 1\\
& t \mapsto 0
\end{align}$$

[image]

I understand why by the fundamental theorem of homomorphisms, given this homomorphism, $H$ is normal. So the fact that it is a normal subgroup is not the issue - in fact, [$[D_4:H]=2,$ also proving that $H$ is normal](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Index_2_is_Normal).

But the question is how are the arrows in the map above generated from $r\mapsto 1$ and $t\mapsto 0.$

Comment: Hint: consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as an additive group and remember that for $x, y \in D_4, \phi(xy) = \phi(x) + \phi(y).$

Comment: @Aurel Thank you. So, for example, $\phi(r^3)=\phi(r\cdot r\cdot r)=\phi(r)+\phi(r)+\phi(r)=1+1+1\equiv_3 1.$ And $\phi (tr^2)=\phi(t) + \phi(r^2) =0+0.$